# Get the live streaming link of video using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, video-streaming, m3u8

I need to extract the live channel streaming link from the [website](https://www.airtelxstream.in/livetv-channels/zee-news/MWTV_LIVETVCHANNEL_428). I am new to this and can't understand what am I doing wrong.

**NOTE:** The website first requires me to login with my number. So that may be the issue.

I found the .m3u8 link of the video but using it gives me Response 403. How do I get the video link.

```
import requests

video = requests.get('https://liveb.airtelxstream.in/zeenews/smil:common.smil/chunklist_b896000_DVR_sleng.m3u8')

print(video)
print(video.text)
```

Output is,

```
<Response [403]>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>MissingKey</Code><Message>Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value</Message></Error>
```

Comment: You should use a requests Session object, and first submit the login form for the website. It will store your session cookie, and then you may be able to get the m3u8.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it? Also login is done via mobile number and otp.